# Can't get data from firebase in react chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using ApexChartJs for my react project, but when I tried to fetch dynamic data from my firebase database, then show me `undefined`.

[image]

here is my part of code from my project:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";
import { auth, db } from "./firebase";
import { useCollection } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";


  const [dataPoint, setDataPoint] = useState([]);
  const query = db.collection("data");
  const [snapshot, loading, error] = useCollection(query);
  const [series, setSeries] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSeries([
      {
        name: "Desktops",
        data: snapshot?.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().value),
      },
    ]);
  }, [snapshot]);

  console.log(series);
```

data in the firebase look like:

[image]

firebase configure file:

```
import firebase from "firebase";

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyC2mfjPdIdXxGgJFqqVviw32xoaEMxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "chart-app-4591b.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "chart-app-4591b",
  storageBucket: "chart-app-4591b.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "995691438244",
  appId: "1:995691438244:web:6d945f72ff51d444664631",
  measurementId: "G-2B9ZFG6E33",
};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = app.firestore();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const auth = firebase.auth;

export { db, provider, auth };
```

Comment: Please show snapshot?.docs

Comment: @Viet I have added one more piece of info from firebase from where I need to fetch data.

Comment: Please show in `console.log`

Comment: Yeah, I have added console output on the first image.

Comment: `console.log( snapshot?.docs)`

Comment: Could you add your `Firebase` app configuration (`import { auth, db } from "./firebase";`)?

Comment: @Viet it shows me `undefined`

Comment: It is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your *firebase* app is well set-up and configured appropriately, the main issue that may lead an `undefined` query result is that the result are still being loaded.

To overcome this, you should update your `series` state whenever the `loading` property changes (along with query result `snapshot` changes):

```
  const query = db.collection("data");
  const [snapshot, loading, error] = useCollection(query);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSeries([
      {
        name: "Desktops",
        data: snapshot?.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().value),
      },
    ]);
  }, [loading, snapshot]);
```

You should provide alternative `error` handling as well for state update.

### Update (per the permission error)

A common error source would be the lack of privileges to read and write from the configured *Firestore* DB highlighted by below error message:

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions
```

To allow all reads and writes **for test only mode (should never be the case for a production system)**, you can set below *Security Rules* for the database:

```
// Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more on [*Cloud Firestore Security Rules* in the official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#allow-all).

Comment: Hi @tmarwen thanks for your explanation, I knew the problem in my query, but I'm wondering you may see above the picture about firebase db, I wrote `data` then assign the value, then why I can't get the value.

Comment: Did the fix / update I posted lead different results? Could you please add the firebase setup part I already request in main OP comment?

Comment: I have added firebase setup file on the main post. If any mistake then please let me know.

Comment: The configuration is correct unless I am missing something. Would you please log (`console.log`) both `snapshot`, `loading` and `error` in one shot: `console.log(snapshot, loading, error)`

Comment: All of the three? I am not pointing to the `snapshot` value only.

Comment: `snapshot` is `undefined` and `loading` is `false` and for `error` it shows me `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions`

Comment: Then you don't have sufficient permissions to access data. Make sure to either have `testMode` set for your Firestore project or update the Security Rules you already have set up.

Comment: Thanks, man, I just go to the firebase DB rules and did `false` to `true` that's it solved my problem, yeah you can update your answer then anyone can get help.

Comment: Just updated the answer, glad to be in help.